# How or where can I edit in-game text?

Tags: league-of-legends

Nowadays League of Legends game version : **3.15**

Is there a way to change any **in-game** text?

For instance:

- When you win a game, instead of reading "victory", you read "AWESOME!!".
- Instead of this:
  [image]

  You read this:
  [image]

Comment: Why the downvote? It's just player customization.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about those 4 lines or any and every text string in the game?

Comment: lol those pings

Comment: Any and every text string.

Comment: Well I know what I'm doing for the rest of the night now...

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your server, (NA, EUW, etc), the file is in a different place. 
For the current release (3.15) on the NA server, the file you wish to edit is located here:

> C:\Riot Games\League of
>   Legends\RADS\projects\lol_game_client_en_us\managedfiles\0.0.0.132\Data\Menu\fontconfig_en_US.txt

In your case, for LAS, search for a file with "fontconfig" in the lol_game_client_es_mx, instead of lol_game_client_en_us directory, and you should be able to find it.
The fontconfig_en_us.txt file is all the text in the game. Recommending you open this with NP++, or a similar editor, the four pings are lines 667-700. Changing the words in quotations will change the text ingame.

This modification will not get you banned, for custom skins, custom maps, etc, are not ban worthy, as they do not influence gameplay.

Comment: The ".132" had to be changed to ".135" for me to get to this folder.

Comment: I can't find the folder 0.0.0.132... close to it are folders 0.0.0.117 and 0.0.0.152

Comment: Just search for "fontconfig" in your lol_game_client_es_mx folder. The file may be in a different place for the different servers

Comment: Can't find the fontconfig file. It's not there. I remember downloading an old version from the forums and tried to paste it in many version folders (0.0.0.172, below and so on, even sometimes creating ones like the 132), but I couldn't make it work.