# Is it possible to edit in-game text in Monkey Island special edition?

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se, the-secret-of-monkey-island-se

How can I edit the in game text?

There must be a way since there are translations around the web. Maybe a software or editing some specific game files?

**Sidenote:** Some years ago there was a small software tool to translate the GTA2 in-game text that I used, I was hoping something similar could exist for Monkey Island.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about deconstructing a game to modify the text.  That's outside of our expertise.  This may be better at GameDev, but double-check their FAQ to make sure it would be acceptable there.

Comment: I'm sorry @Frank, but I saw [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147702/how-or-where-can-i-edit-in-game-text) +3 upvoted question and thought it would be OK

Comment: actually questions like this are on-topic here since they are directly related to a game but there are still some people who don't like them so don't expect too many upvotes...

Comment: @Jutschge, I'm not here for upvotes, just some answers :)

Comment: Hmm.  I don't frequent the LoL tag a lot.  If Monkey Island stores their text in a text file, I suppose we could help with locating that for you.  But if we have to decompile the game to get at those data files, that's getting beyond what we can really help with.  This would definitely be better if you removed the request for a tool recommendation.  That is categorically off-topic.  The rest is grey, and I'm willing to see where the community sits on it.

Comment: @Frank, I'm not requesting any tool. I'm asking if it is possible to edit the in-game text on Monkey Island, as you can see by reading the question title. Now, if it involves a tool or not, I don't care. I just gave an example of a way to edit the in-game text in another game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late response, but it is possible to do so for both Special Editions of the Monkey Island games (Secret of Monkey Island and LeChuck's Revenge).

If you are interested in translating the game, rather than editing the text to something else in one of the already supported languages, then the translation process could be trickier than just editing and re-importing the text. It actually depends on the charset of the target language and you will probably need to edit the font files too if the target language uses non-latin characters outside those already supported by the game.

There is a related [discussion topic about it over on lucasforums.com](http://www.lucasforums.com/showthread.php?t=201694)
I also created a tool in python for the purposes of the (fan) greek translation for the games. It is [currently on git hub as an open source project](https://github.com/ShadowNate/MISETranslator). Note that the binary version linked in the aforementioned lucasforum topic is old (superseded), so I suggest that you use the source code instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I haven't managed to find a tool that allows what I intend. I will check it later and see if I can (finally) translate the in-game text. Again, thanks!